# What do we call a non-technical person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing some text for the website of my hosting company and I simply cannot figure this one out.

I currently have the following sentence:

> We provide reliable hosting for creative professionals and X

I am very confused about X. I need a term for the following:

> *those who want their own website but do not have a creative professional hired, but rather handle everything on their own*

Naturally, I cannot say:

> We provide reliable hosting for creative professionals and non-technical people

Any help anyone?

My question is **not** a duplicate as the context is completely different. Normally this would not be a problem however in this case the term we're looking for is completely different than those already answered in the other question.

Comment: When describing the process of explaining highly technical stuff to non-experts, I often call it *translating the jargon into **human***.

Comment: Hmmm, trying to come up with an antonym for "techie" I first light on "stuckee".  From there I drift off towards "schmuck".  Not really satisfying the requirements, I suppose.

Comment: If you are contrasting the two then you seem to be suggesting by your question that *creative* = *technical*. Hmm.

Comment: Hackers might say *[luser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luser)* or *[lamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamer)* though they are too derogatory for what you need!

Comment: Users are voting to close this question as a duplicate, but they're WRONG! Read the question in the body, the OP needs a word or expression for a **non-expert**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We provide reliable hosting for creative professionals and for **self-reliant clients / individuals**.

Where the term *[self-reliant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-reliant)* suggests a person or persons who have acquired a certain level of expertise without necessarily being professionals.

Comment: I'm feeling so dumb now... 'individual' was exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I didn't think of that! Accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my two grains of sand:

"... for creative professionals and enthusiasts alike"

"... for users of all levels, from beginners to creative professionals"

Comment: enthusiasts is good

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to [users](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/user):

User:

> - One who uses a computer, computer program, or online service.
>     (AHD)

- ....for creative professionals and other users.

Answer (score 2):

Any attempt to draw attention to their non-technical nature might be wrong (they might be very technically capable in other fields - just not websites) and, in any case, will inevitably have negative connotations to some (amateur, technophobe, noob, etc.).

Therefore, I suggest

> We provide reliable hosting for creative professionals and the wider
>   public

Answer (score 2):

We provide reliable hosting for creative professionals and **lay amateurs**.

> - [lay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay) - (adj) - not trained in a certain profession : not having a lot of knowledge about a certain thing.
> - [amateur](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amateur) - (noun) -  one who engages in an art, science, study, or athletic activity as a pastime rather than as a profession.

Comment: +1 -My first two thoughts, but I would say *layperson* or amateur.

Comment: @W9WBH  An amateur can be highly skilled, that's why the "lay".

Answer (score 2):

Suggest:

> 'We provide reliable hosting for creative **professionals** and **non-professionals** alike.'

I am trying to emphasise equality of service provision, whether or not the client has a professional interest. I would read the sentence as saying the adjective, 'creative', applies to both types of client.

Answer (score 0):

technophobe

> /ˈtɛknə(ʊ)fəʊb/
>
> noun
>
> noun: technophobe; plural noun: technophobes; noun: techno-phobe;
>   plural noun: techno-phobes
>
> a person who fears, dislikes, or avoids new technology.
>
> https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=technophobe

The real problem IMO is your use of 'and'.  It gives the impression you can't be professional and non-technical at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, but calling my customers that is a bit insulting, no?

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards - Oh absolutely it is. The problem is that your sentence is structured to insult *anyone* who comes after 'creative professionals'. Whatever you follow it with, you make them seem like non-creative amateurs.